# Why this.state.count++ won't work in this.setState({})

Tags: reactjs, state, increment

I have tried this answer

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count++,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Change!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And I realized when i just change the increment function it all works fine

```
increment(){
  this.setState({
      count:this.state.count+1
})}
```

I was wondering why would increment() work when this.state.count+1 is used and not work this.state.count++ is used..

Comment: If you increment it in-place and then call setState with the same value then it hasn't changed so it doesn't update the html.

Comment: Use: `++count:this.state.count`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -  wouldn't it be `count: ++this.state.count`? I''ve never seen that this is a valid syntax...

Comment: Agree with Oleg Valter, where you put the '++' matters, but putting it on the key is pretty strange

Comment: Btw, Naveen - this is governed by the difference between "postfix" and "prefix" increment / decrement. You might think that it should not matter since the `this.state.count` is incremented, but `setState` receives `count: value_before_increment` if postfix, therefore overriding the increment ( exactly what Ian mentioned above )

Answer (score 2):

When you use the increment/decrement operator in postfix as you have, the return value is the variable **before** it has been updated. However, if you were to use it in prefix, it would make the update and then return the result. Using `count + 1` is similar in this way, as it takes the value of count, adds one and then returns a result.

You can test this simply by hopping into a browser console and doing the following experiment:

```
a=1;
console.log(a++); //returns 1
console.log(a); //returns 2

b=1;
console.log(++b); //returns 2
console.log(b); //returns 2
```

To conclude:

- Using `this.state.count++` is returning the original value to `setState()`
- Using `this.state.count + 1` is returning the original value +1 to `setState()`

[This short article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed) explains it quite well.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem is the order in which operations are applied and with how increment works. In your case it is (roughly, actually there is more going on like `GetValue` abstract operations) as follows:

1. An internal `[[Get]]` method is called on `this.state.count`
2. An internal `[[Set]]` method is called on `this.state.count` with result of step 1 + 1
3. An internal `[[Set]]` method is called on `({}).count` with old value

Thus, after step 3, you have `{ count: 1 }` in state and your object as `{ count: 0 }`

**setState**

Under the hood of `setState`, React does the following (again, roughly):

4. Calls `enqueueSetState` with the object from step 3 on Component's `updater` which pushes it onto state update queue.
5. When state is updated, `Object.assign()` is called on old state in a loop traversing new partial states, therefore overriding `count` to `0`.

**Solution**

As mentioned in comments, switch to prefix increment as on step 3 the value returned will be the new value:

`{ count : ++this.state.count }`

**Reference**

1. Increment reference on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)
2. Internal methods [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)
3. Postfix increment [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-postfix-increment-operator)
4. Prefix increment [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-prefix-increment-operator)
5. `Object.assign()` ref on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)